# First progressBar in listview doesn't progress

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-progressbar

I have a very bad issue. 
I have a listview with an adapter.

```
public class MediaAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<Media> {


public MediaAdapter(Context context, Media[] items) {
    super(context, R.layout.mediaitemlist, items);
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView media_name;
    TextView media_path;
    TextView media_version;
    TextView media_type;
    ProgressBar pb;
}   

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = (View)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mediaitemlist, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.media_name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_name);
        holder.media_path = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_path);
        holder.media_type = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_type);
        holder.media_version = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_version);
        holder.pb = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.itemprogressdl);
        view.setTag(holder);

        //Maybe the problem is here ???????????
        getItem(position).setmProgressBar((ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.itemprogressdl));
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Media rowItem = (Media) getItem(position);

    holder.media_name.setText(rowItem.get_Name());
    holder.media_path.setText(rowItem.get_Path());
    holder.media_type.setText(rowItem.get_TypeString());
    holder.media_version.setText("" + rowItem.get_Version());
    rowItem.setmProgressBar(holder.pb);
    return view;
}
```

}

Here, the mediaitemlist Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/listitembackground" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/media_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/media_path"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/media_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/media_version"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/media_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/media_version"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/itemprogressdl"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/media_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/media_name"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/media_version" 
    android:max="100"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The progressBar is an attribute of a media class. One Media class have is own progress according to his place in the listView.

But, all the progressBar attributes are good, except the first of the listView. If I click on the second or over, I can see the progressBar progresses, but not with the first.

So, why the first progressBar doesn't work and the next work?

If you need more code,comments or other, ask me.

Comment: did you tried `holder.pb.setProgress()`

Comment: no, because i update the progress in a third class like this : oneMedia.getProgressBar().setProgress(); and it works with the item over the second but not with the first, and I dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

try moving this line

```
getItem(position).setmProgressBar((ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.itemprogressdl));
```

out of the if..else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View view = convertView;
    Media rowItem = (Media) getItem(position);
    if (view == null) {
        view = (View)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mediaitemlist, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.media_name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_name);
        holder.media_path = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_path);
        holder.media_type = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_type);
        holder.media_version = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.media_version);
        holder.pb = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.itemprogressdl);
        view.setTag(holder);

        //Maybe the problem is here ???????????
        getItem(position).setmProgressBar((ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.itemprogressdl));
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        rowItem.setmProgressBar(holder.pb);
    }

    holder.media_name.setText(rowItem.get_Name());
    holder.media_path.setText(rowItem.get_Path());
    holder.media_type.setText(rowItem.get_TypeString());
    holder.media_version.setText("" + rowItem.get_Version());

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I cant call rowItem, it is define after the condition.... Or maybe i move Media rowItem = (Media) getItem(position); before the condition ?

Comment: In fact, all progressBar are null the first time. why ?

Comment: Just the progressBar or the textview as well??

Comment: Sry, I make a mistake, progressBars arent null, but I dont see them, like if there are out of the screen

Comment: Just the progressBar, All the textView are set and are correct

Comment: could you post what setmProgressBar does? I didn't find in documentation, so I suppose youve made it

Comment: Yep I made It. I send you below in 1 min

Comment: public class Media{
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
public void setmProgressBar(ProgressBar mProgressBar) {
  //Log.d(TAG,mProgressBar.toString());
  this.mProgressBar = mProgressBar;
 }